# Updating a table column with oldest date in each row, except where the oldest date has already passed?

Tags: sql, postgresql, datetime, sql-update, unpivot

I would like to update the contents of the `Date1` column to reflect the oldest date in each row, *unless* the date has already passed (`Date1 < current date`), **in which case i'd like `Date1` to be populated with the 2nd oldest date in the row**.

For added context, The table has thousands of rows and ~15 columns, only a handful of which are dates. I've used the `least` function in the past to update this column with the oldest date in each row, but I can't figure out how to update it with the 2nd oldest date if the oldest date is prior to the current date.

| ID | Date 1 | Date 2 | Date 3 | Date 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 001 |  | 01/14/2022 | 01/15/2022 | 01/16/2022 |
| 002 |  | 04/15/2019 | 03/20/2021 | 06/16/2021 |

Comment: What if second oldest date has also passed?

Comment: Or to put it another way,  are you looking for the date that is closest to the target date without being less then it?

Comment: If the 2nd oldest date has passed, then I'd want the 3rd oldest date returned and so on. There are a total of 7 date fields to draw from in the table, excluding date 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the oldest date today or later. You can do this without a subquery, using `least()` and conditional expressions:

```
update mytable t
set date1 = least(
    case when date2 >= current_date then date2 end,
    case when date3 >= current_date then date3 end,
    case when date4 >= current_date then date4 end
)
```

The `case` expression turns "past" dates to `null`, which `least()` ignores.

An alternative unpivots the columns to rows and then uses filtering and  aggregation:

```
update mytable t
set date1 = (
    select min(date)
    from (values (date2), (date3), (date4)) d(dt)
    where dt >= current_date
)
```

Comment: The first solution works well. The only problem I run into is when all available dates are prior to the current date. In this case it overwrites the value in the date1 column with null, which is not ideal. This query would be perfect otherwise.

Comment: Would adding something like where dt >=current_date **AND * dt<>** to the 2nd query work? I'm not sure how to say that all dates are not equal in SQL.

Answer (score 0):

So something like. You would need to modify to create appropriate `WHERE` conditions for the `UPDATE`. This is obviously untested on your setup, so try on test/expendable data.:

```
WITH dt AS 
    (SELECT unnest(ARRAY['11/02/2020'::date,  '12/31/2020'::date, '01/01/2021'::date]) AS dt_val) 
UPDATE 
    some_table
SET 
    dt1 = 
(SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    dt 
WHERE 
    dt_val >= '12/30/2020'::date 
ORDER BY 
    dt_val 
LIMIT 1);

 dt_val   
------------
 12/31/2020
```

Where you would replace the values in `ARRAY` with the field names. The query creates an array from the date values and then `unnest(s)` the array to create rows. It then looks for the row values that are greater then or equal to the target date where the rows are ordered by the date values. The result is limited to the date value that is oldest by the `LIMIT 1`.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. Im getting an error indicating that the fields I input in place of the values in ARRAY don't exist, though they do. I've replaced the values in the array with my field names, some_table with the name of my table(sol_dates), and dt1 with the name of the field im trying to update(sol_date). Notice anything obviously wrong?:

Comment: WITH dt AS     
 (SELECT unnest(ARRAY[pi_sol_date_using_sor::date,  pl_sol_date_using_sor::date, pi_sol_date_using_sob::date,  pl_sol_date_using_sob::date, wd_sol_date_using_sor::date, wd_sol_date_using_sob::date, wd_sol_date_using_sod::date]) AS dt_val) 
UPDATE 
    sol_dates
SET 
    sol_date = 
(SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    dt
WHERE 
    dt_val >= '12/30/2020'::date 
ORDER BY 
    dt_val 
LIMIT 1);

Comment: Yes, you did not specify where the field names are coming from. So, `SELECT unnest(ARRAY[pi_sol_date_using_sor::date, pl_sol_date_using_sor::date, pi_sol_date_using_sob::date, pl_sol_date_using_sob::date, wd_sol_date_using_sor::date, wd_sol_date_using_sob::date, wd_sol_date_using_sod::date]) AS dt_val FROM some_table`